# Want L.OpacityControls to activate after selecting an overlayLayer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, transparency-opacity

Edited to show working code. Although not working 100% and it involves some ugly workarounds which I assume are fixable.

Original problem: I'm using `L.control.layers` to display a selection of layers. After selecting a layer I want [`L.Control.opacitySlider`](https://github.com/lizardtechblog/Leaflet.OpacityControls) to show up so can see the underlying basemap. `L.Control.opacitySlider` uses [`L.control.activeLayers`](https://github.com/vogdb/Leaflet.ActiveLayers) which can't be used in the initial display of the map because there is no overlayLayer (and `L.control.layers` can't be used because it doesn't reveal the `overlayLayer`). But I don't think it helps to have to go from `L.control.layers` to `L.control.activeLayers`. It seems to this noob that using the event that captures the selection of the overlayLayer to trigger the `opacitySlider` is an approach, but I've not idea how to do that. My attempts are near the end of the code. `leaflet-control-layers leaflet-control` is the class of the element that contains the `L.control.layers`.[![`leaflet-control-layers leaflet-control` is the class of the element that contains the `L.control.layers`.]

Main fix is using the suggested: `map.on('overlayadd', function (event)` … . After retrieving the `current` layer as opposed to all the `overlayLayers`.  Left to be done: 1) making sure only one overlayLayer is selected, 2) killing bugs in other views, 3) refactoring this `edit` to merge code with the `show` view (not shown here).

Map called basically from the edit.html.erb (Rails)

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  $(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
    var popupText = "&le;<%= @street.dateEarliest %><br><%= @street.prevName %><br>&ge;<%= @street.dateLatest %><br><%= @street.currentName %>";
    editMap(popupText); // in streets.js
  });
</script>
```

Relevant portion of `streets.js` (originally part of edit.html.erb, but moved to take advantage of browser debugging):

```
function editMap(popupText) {
// Map tile URLs
var hamlin1908url = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mtnbiker/cj3gnezpq00152rt5o6g3kyqp/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibXRuYmlrZXIiLCJhIjoiNmI5ZmZjMzAyNzJhY2Q0N2ZlN2E1ZTdkZjBiM2I1MTUifQ.6R3ptz9ejWpxcdZetLLRqg', 
  Hill1928aws =    'https://crores.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/1928Hills/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
  baistDetailAws = 'https://crores.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/baistDetail/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
  baistKMaws     = "https://crores.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/bkm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
  rueger1902aws  = "https://crores.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/1902rueger/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
  woods1908url   = "https://crores.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/1908woods/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
  sanborn1888km1aURL = "https://crores.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/1888SanbornKM1a/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
  sanborn1894km1aURL = "https://crores.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/1894SanbornKM1a/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
  osmUrl    = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      esriUrl   = 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServe\
  r/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
  googleUrl = 'http://www.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs=s@189&gl=cn&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}'

// Links for attribution
var osmLink  = '<a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>',
  osmCopy = '<a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
  mapboxCopy = '<a href="https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/">Mapbox</a>',
  esriLink = '<a href="https://www.esri.com/">Esri</a>',
  mbLink   = '<a href="https://mapbox.com/">OpenStreetMap</a>',
  rumseyLink = '<a href="http://www.davidrumsey.com">The David Rumsey Map Collection</a>',
  csunLink = "",
  bigBlogMapLink = 'http://www.bigmapblog.com'

// Attribution
  var osmAttrib = '&copy; ' + osmLink + ' Contributors',
  esriAttrib = 'i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP,\
and the GIS User Community & '+ esriLink,
  mapboxAttrib = '&copy; ' + mapboxCopy + '&copy;' + osmCopy,
  mwAttrib ='https://thinkwhere.wordpress.com',
  rumseyAttrib = rumseyLink,
  csunAttrib = csunLink,
  bigBlogMapAttrib = bigBlogMapLink,
  hamlinAttrib = ""

// Putting together as a Leaftlet tileLayer. First variable is the URL of the tiles
var rueger1902Map       = L.tileLayer(rueger1902aws,    {attribution: mapboxAttrib}),
    osmMap      = L.tileLayer(osmUrl,       {attribution: osmAttrib}),
    esriMap     = L.tileLayer(esriUrl,      {attribution: esriAttrib}),
    bing = L.tileLayer.bing('AtGe6-aWfp_sv8DMsQeQBgTVE0AaVI2WcT42hmv12YSO-PPROsm9_UvdRyL91jav'),
    google      = L.tileLayer(googleUrl,      {attribution: 'Google'}),
    hill1928 = L.tileLayer(Hill1928aws,  {attribution: bigBlogMapAttrib, layers: 'Hill1928', maxZoom:18 }),
    baistDetail = L.tileLayer(baistDetailAws, {attribution: rumseyAttrib, layers: 'BaistDetail', maxZoom:19 }),
    baistKM     = L.tileLayer(baistKMaws,   {attribution: rumseyAttrib}),
    rueger1902  = L.tileLayer(rueger1902aws),
    hamlin1908   = L.tileLayer(hamlin1908url),
    woods1908    = L.tileLayer(woods1908url,  {attribution: rumseyAttrib, maxZoom:17 }),
    sanborn1894km1a = L.tileLayer(sanborn1894km1aURL,  {attribution: csunAttrib}),
    sanborn1888km1a = L.tileLayer(sanborn1888km1aURL,  {attribution: csunAttrib})

var overlayLayers = {
  // "<span style='color: blue'>1921 Baist detail</span>"   : baistDetail,
  // "<span style='color: blue'>1921 Baist Key Map</span>"  : baistKM,
  "1921 Baist detail"   : baistDetail,
  "1921 Baist Key Map"  : baistKM,
  "1928 Hill"    : hill1928,
  "1908 Wood"    : woods1908,
  "1908 Hamlin"  : hamlin1908,
  "1902 Rueger"  : rueger1902,
  "1894 Sanborn" : sanborn1894km1a,
  "1888 Sanborn" : sanborn1888km1a
};
var baseLayers = {
  "<span style='color: green'>Bing</span>"               : bing,
  "<span style='color: orange'>OSM Street</span>"        : osmMap, 
  "<span style='color: green' >ESRI Satellite</span>"    : esriMap,
  "<span style='color: green' >Google Satellite</span>"  : google
}                             

var map = L.map('map', {
    center: new L.LatLng(34.05, -118.25),
    zoom: 13,
    layers: [osmMap, hill1928], // have to figure out how to make the second item a blank map. Probably need to find a more robust solution and actually figure out how to make it work right
    zoomControl: true
});
L.tileLayer.bing('AtGe6-aWfp_sv8DMsQeQBgTVE0AaVI2WcT42hmv12YSO-PPROsm9_UvdRyL91jav').addTo(map); 
var streetExtentArray = gon.streetExtentArray; // works better with this even if though below

if (streetExtentArray.length > 2) {
  var arrayStreetExtent = JSON.parse(gon.streetExtentArray); // If not inside if, errors when streetExtentArray doesn't exist, but TODO seems to need to be reloaded to show page
  map.fitBounds(arrayStreetExtent);
  L.polyline(arrayStreetExtent).addTo(map)
                               .bindPopup(popupText).openPopup()
  ;
}
L.control.activeLayers(baseLayers, overlayLayers).addTo(map);
var addOpacitySlider = function(currentLayer) {
console.log("218. Got into addOpacitySlider. currentLayer: " + currentLayer);
var control = L.control.activeLayers(baseLayers, overlayLayers);
var opacitySlider = new L.Control.opacitySlider();
map.addControl(opacitySlider);
// Ugly workaround. Should find the L.tilelayer info directly
switch (currentLayer) {
  case "1921 Baist detail":
    currentLayer = baistDetail;
    break;
  case "<span style='color: blue'>1921 Baist detail</span>":
    currentLayer = baistDetail;
    break;
  case "<span style='color: blue'>1921 Baist Key Map</span>":
    currentLayer = baistKM;
    break;
  case "1921 Baist Key Map":
    currentLayer = baistKM;
    break;
  case "1928 Hill":
    currentLayer = hill1928;
    break;
  case "1908 Wood":
    currentLayer = woods1908;
    break;
  case "1908 Hamlin":
    currentLayer = hamlin1908;
    break;
  case "1902 Rueger":
    currentLayer = rueger1902;
    break;
  case "1894 Sanborn":
    currentLayer = sanborn1894km1a;
    break;
  case "1888 Sanborn":
    currentLayer = sanborn1888km1a;
    break;
  default:
    currentLayer = baistKM;
    break;
}
opacitySlider.setOpacityLayer(currentLayer); 
}
map.on('overlayadd', function (event) {
  console.log("261. overlayadd event.name: " + event.name);
  var currentLayer = event.name;
  addOpacitySlider(currentLayer);
});
```

[Beta site](https://stark-cove-20051.herokuapp.com/streets/6) Opacity slider working but buggy (functionally similar to code above, but refactored). (https://github.com/MtnBiker/historical-streets-la).  Built using Ruby on Rails for access to PostGIS.

The many suggestions from the persistent @NettaB helped get this working.

Comment: Try changing `$("leaflet-control-layers leaflet-control")` to  `$(".leaflet-control-layers.leaflet-control")`

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately didn't help. I also tried `leaflet-control-layers-selector.` I tried in Chrome: Event Listener Breakpoints > Mouse > click, but more than 100 events occur. I guess I need to use this tool better or?

Comment: 1. Can try this selector? `$(".leaflet-control-layers-selector")` 2. Just to be clear, you want the opacityslider to initiate after choosing from the leaflet-control-layers-list?

Comment: You could also try using the event `map.on('baselayerchange', function(e) {}`

Comment: 1. Tried the selector. The whole line is `$(".leaflet-control-layers-selector").onclick = addOpacitySlider; ` and 2. Yes, because there may not be any overlayLayers to work with until one has been selected. Not sure how to implement your third and fourth suggestions. 

I have reworked the code and will repost it in a while (will be hours before I can do this.) I moved the script from the html.erb into a proper .js file. Had to do that to track events. But I'm very much a noobie at almost all of thisl. Thank you again.

Comment: There's an overlayadd event ( [link](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-overlayadd)) that you can use. Suggested article ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103489/leaflet-layer-control-events))

Comment: Tried (in place of the selector onclick) `map.on('overlayadd', addOpacitySlider);` but get an error `"Control doesn't have any active base layer!"` even if I go through the error, then an overlayLayer shows; and I try to load another overlayLayer (one is showing) and still get the same error. But this approach seems more to the point than trying to get the selector. Will look later and will read the links more thoroughly. Looks like you're in the right territory. Also should learn how I would have found those options.

Comment: Glad to hear that, good luck and keep the post updated. The leaflet documentation is really good, I'm  usually looking for a direction here and then dig into the documentation.

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment, but `map.on('overlayadd', addOpacitySlider);` did work. In my rush I hadn't realized the error was within the function. @NettaB: Thank you for the fix. I gave it an up, but don't see a way to check it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a map overlayadd event ([link](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-overlayadd)) that listens to overlay change/add.

Suggested article ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103489/leaflet-layer-control-events))